# Exporting Xcode app for individuals to download over web server

Tags: ios, xcode, build, signing

I have an Xcode app that I have just finished developing. I do not wish to put this app on the App Store. Instead I would like to build the app and then serve it over my local host, so anyone connected to the URL on my network can simply download the app and use it.

How exactly can I achieve this?

One issue I am running into when selecting the organizer after archiving is that the buttons for export is grayed out. I am signing as my (personal  team) but it does not seem to cooperate. How can I do this?

Comment: You can by using an Enterprise developer account. Lots of resources in the internet to help you get started.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307432/how-to-distribute-enterprise-ipa-files

https://medium.com/wso2-iot/how-to-export-in-house-developed-ios-app-as-an-enterprise-application-dc087bdd64c3

Comment: You could also use TestFlight which will allow people to download your app without publishing onto the App Store

Comment: It looks like you have downloaded the Xcode from developer apple website and you are developing the app under simulator and a device connected via cable or wifi to your computer, without buying a "Apple Developer Program for Individuals". Is that your case?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here:

- Enterprise developer account

Additional cost and can't upload to AppStore, users when installing for the first time have to trust the developer before the app will run

- Ad Hoc profile

Requires adding UDIDs for all of the devices that you want to be able to run.  Profiles will eventually expire (12 months I think).  Would usually use this option with a service like HockeyApp/Diawi

- Testflight

If you use internal testers then limited to 100 users that have to be invited to the Apple developer tea.  If using external testers then can have much higher number of users, but app has to go through a short review process similar to when submitting for review to the app store